# Using handlerbars in sendgrid but curly brackets are not removed

Tags: c#, sendgrid

I have this html code

```
string source =
    @"<div class=""entry"">
      <h1>{{title}}</h1>
      <div class=""body"">
        {{body}}
      </div>
    </div>";
```

Then I doing this

```
var myMessage = new SendGridMessage();
myMessage.From = new EmailAddress(mailInfo.From, mailInfo.FromDisplayName);
myMessage.SetGlobalSubject(mailInfo.Subject);


for (var i = 0; i < recipientIdAndEmail.Count; i++)
{
    myMessage.AddTo(new EmailAddress(recipientIdAndEmail[i].Email, recipientIdAndEmail[i].Name), i);
    myMessage.AddSubstitution("title", "mohsin in title", i);
    myMessage.AddSubstitution("body", "your_body_content_here", i);
}

myMessage.HtmlContent = source;
await _sendGridClient.SendEmailAsync(myMessage);
```

The result is that the title and body are replaced but {{}} are still there.

I am not using dynamic templates but have the html in my code base.